# Debian Wheezy rebooting instead of powering off

Tags: linux, power-management, shutdown, x86

I'm having a weird issue with my Debian Wheezy desktop. When I try to shutdown the system (either from Gnome or from the command line with `shutdown -h now`) the computer automatically reboots.

The weirdest thing is that the last message before rebooting is "Will now halt"... and a few seconds later, the computer restarts. After waiting for the system to start, if I issue `shutdown -h now` from the console (before starting GNOME), the computer shutdowns cleanly, and *stays* off.

Although I know that I could leave the computer on indefenitely (after all, this is not a Windows box), I prefer to shut it down properly.

Is there some configuration file and/or option I should look at to solve this issue?

***Background info***

- Debian 7.5 "Wheezy" 64 bit
- Processor: Intel Core i7
- Motherboard: ASUSTeK P8B75-M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This thread had many suggestions that look like good leads for you to follow up with.

- [After shutting down desktops often reboots](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1429094)

### Things to try

***idea #1 - systemd***

If your system uses systemd try using this:

```
$ systemctl poweroff
```

***idea #2 - blacklist kernel module mei_me***

> This mei_me ( Intel Management Engine Interface) for Mobile Intel Express Chipset, causes a lot of trouble.
>
> You can blacklist the module, you could lose functionality that I'm not aware of.
>
> If your laptop supports it you may be able to disable it in your BIOS.
>   I read people having success disabling it, though their all different issues.

***idea #3 - interrogate journalctl boot messages***

Take a look at the `journalctl` for feedback on what's causing the system to reboot.

```
$ sudo journalctl -b
```

***idea #4 - Add kernel parameter acpi=force***

Try adding the following to your kernel's boot parameters. These can be appended to the end of your kernel's line in `/etc/grub2.cfg`.

```
linux   /vmlinuz-3.14.4-100.fc19.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root ro rd.md=0 ... acpi=force ...
```

***idea #5 - Try a different power supply (larger rated)***

> My power supply was 450W. However, I got tired of going around the head until I read on page 23 of the GA-Z87N-WIFI manual which case we use the PCI-E was advisable to use a power supply of 500W or higher, as lower springs would destabilize (possible cause of the reboot).
>
> Made to upgrade to a 650W power supply and reboots after shutdown, never happened.
>
> Conclusion: new graphics cards are hungry for energy. Always check the power requirements of the printing and adjust energy sources.

***idea #6 - disable WOL (Wake On LAN)***

> By default, the Wake-up LAN is enabled in BIOS (Power Manegement). As I have a Synology NAS configured for my private network, the "trickster" is sending packets to the network and enables me to Linux machine after doing this shutdown.
>
> I followed your recommendation (I disabled the Wake-up LAN) and everything works as expected.

***idea #7 - bug in kernel with xhci module***

> xhci: Fix spurious wakeups after S5 on Haswell

*Source [Bug 66171 - [PATCH]Poweroff doesn't work, it just reboots](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66171)*

Comment: blacklisting mei_me and mei modules worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on my Fedora 22 and Arch installation. After reading [this bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66171) I added `xhci_hcd.quirks=262144` to my `/etc/default/grub` boot options.

Comment: Tried all of the above options. This was the only thing to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and none of the solutions above worked for me. turns out it was [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=766338)
The workaround mentioned there worked for me:

```
dpkg --purge kexec-tools
```